# React: Map function with two parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a React tutorial that creates a clickable 5 star rating system, and am stuck on what seems like a basic Javascript point. In the anonymous map function below, why is the `n` necessary?

When I try removing the `n`, the app begins returning "NaN out of 5 stars" instead of a real number. But why is this? The `n` seemingly isn't even used in the function at all.

```
{createArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => (
        <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(i + 1)}
        />
      ))}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: you need to tell JS that you want index, for .map function index is second arg, you can even use map((, i) => (  to tell that I is second arg which will be index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how `map()` works, its 1st argument is always the `currentVaule` and the second one is `index`. You can't reach `index` without stating `currentVaule` or `index` will take its place.

```
function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ommit n then i eventually becomes the first paramter. This is basic JS related issue where if you want to use second argument inside a function, then first argument cannot be ommitted. You can ommit arguments from the end, not from the begining.